# Convert 32 bit binary string of 1's and 0's to Signed Decimal Number in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2012 Express. I have a string of 1's and 0's 32 bits in length.

```
01010010000100010111001101110011
```

How would I convert that to a Signed Decimal Number in a SQL script?

Currently I use a Web Tool online for my answer, and my current searching is not leading me to the answer I need.

Comment: http://improve.dk/converting-between-base-2-10-and-16-in-t-sql/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like below -

```
DECLARE @Binary VARCHAR(100) = '01010010000100010111001101110011';
DECLARE @characters CHAR(36),  
        @result BIGINT,  
        @index SMALLINT,  
        @base BIGINT;
SELECT @characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',  
       @result = 0,  
       @index = 0,
       @base = 2;    
WHILE @index < LEN(@Binary)
BEGIN 
     SELECT @result = @result + POWER(@base, @index) * (CHARINDEX(SUBSTRING(@Binary, LEN(@Binary) - @index, 1), @characters) - 1);
     SET @index = @index + 1;  
END
SELECT @result;
```

This will help you to convert from any base ( I used`@base as 2` for binary) to base 10. Started from far right and moved to the left until we run out of digits. The conversion is the (base ^ index) * digit.

Comment: I would like to thank you Abhishek and also Giorgos Betsos. I ended up using Abhishek's example in my code. Both examples produced the same results, but the results were not Signed, they were Unsigned. So I added this bit of code to the end of Abhishek's code to get my result.

Answer (score 3):

You can perform the conversion with a single T-SQL statement if you use a Tally table:

```
;WITH Tally(i) AS (
   SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS i
   FROM (VALUES (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0)) a(n)
   CROSS JOIN (VALUES (0), (0), (0), (0)) b(n)
)  
SELECT SUM(t.v) AS DecimalNumber 
FROM (
   SELECT POWER(CAST(SUBSTRING(x.d, i, 1) AS DECIMAL(10,0)) * 2, 32 - i)
   FROM (VALUES ('01010010000100010111001101110011')) x(d)
   CROSS JOIN Tally) AS t(v)
```

*Explanation:*

- `Tally` is a table expression returning all values from 1-32.
- Using these values we can extract every single digit out of the binary string using `SUBSTRING`.
- With the use of `POWER` mathematical function we can convert every separate binary digit to decimal.
- Using `SUM` we can add up all separate decimal numbers to get the expected result.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb/5916)

Answer (score 0):

I had to add this code to the end of Abhishek's Code Example to get a Signed number I needed.

```
DECLARE @MyNewExValue INT
IF @result > 2147483647
     BEGIN
         SET @result = @result - (2147483648 * 2)
     END
SET @MyNewExValue = @result
SELECT @MyNewExValue
```

Answer (score 0):

in Addition to [Giorgos Betsos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2149718/giorgos-betsos)'s reply
see ITVF function below:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf_BinaryToDecimal]
(
 @Binary VARCHAR(31)
)
  RETURNS TABLE AS RETURN

  WITH Tally (n) AS
 (
 --32 Rows
    SELECT TOP (LEN (@Binary)) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) -1
    FROM (VALUES (0),(0),(0),(0)) a(n)
    CROSS JOIN (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) b(n)
 )
 SELECT 
 SUM(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(@Binary),n+1,1)  *  POWER(2,n)) TenBase
 FROM Tally 

 /*How to Use*/
 SELECT TenBase 
 FROM udf_BinaryToDecimal ('01010010000100010111')

 /*Result -> 336151*/
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution will work with binary strings of any (bigint) length:

```
DECLARE @input varchar(max) = 
  '01010010000100010111001101110011'

;WITH N(V) AS 
(
  SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER()over(ORDER BY (SELECT 1))
  FROM
    (VALUES(1),(1),(1),(1))M(a),
    (VALUES(1),(1),(1),(1))L(a),
    (VALUES(1),(1),(1),(1))K(a)
)
SELECT SUM(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(@input),V,1)*POWER(CAST(2 as BIGINT), V-1))
FROM   N
WHERE  V <= LEN(@input)
```

*([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43738064/84873))*

It should be noted the most upvoted [solution above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32805480/84873) only works with binary strings exactly 32 bits in length, and a string of `'00000000000000000000000000000000'` returns `1`.