# Convert decimal <--> binary with T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How can I convert binary (base 2 stored as varchar) into decimal (base 10 stored as int or bigint) and the other way around, using T-SQL?

**Example results:**

- `7` (dec) <--> `111` (bin)
- `136` (dec) <--> `10001000` (bin)
- `2123942362` (dec) <--> `1111110100110001100100111011010` (bin)

Comment: What is the source data's type? Decimals and integers are binary values too. If this is a string, you have to *parse* this number, not convert it.

Comment: see *converting base 2 to decimal* here for a udf: http://improve.dk/converting-between-base-2-10-and-16-in-t-sql/

Comment: In other words, if the input is binary data, `cast(@input as int)` is enough: `declare @input varbinary(32)=0x7E98C9DA; select cast(@input as int);`

Comment: @AlexK. I believe I posted a more effective way for that algoritm

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This answer can handle bigint

Convert to bit(varchar containing 1 and 0)

```
DECLARE @input BIGINT = 9223372036854775807

;WITH N(N)AS 
(
  SELECT top 63
    POWER(cast(2 as bigint),
      ROW_NUMBER()over(ORDER BY (SELECT 1))-1)
  FROM
    (VALUES(1),(1),(1),(1))M(a),
    (VALUES(1),(1),(1),(1))L(a),
    (VALUES(1),(1),(1),(1))K(a)
)
SELECT
  COALESCE
  (
    REVERSE
    (
      ( 
        SELECT CAST(@input/N%2 as CHAR(1))
        FROM N 
        WHERE N <= @input
        for xml path(''), type 
      ).value('.', 'varchar(max)')
    )
    , '0'
  )
```

Result:

```
111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
```

Convert varchar containing bit values to bigint

```
DECLARE @input varchar(max) = 
  '111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111'

;WITH N(V) AS 
(
  SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER()over(ORDER BY (SELECT 1))
  FROM
    (VALUES(1),(1),(1),(1))M(a),
    (VALUES(1),(1),(1),(1))L(a),
    (VALUES(1),(1),(1),(1))K(a)
)
SELECT SUM(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(@input),V,1)*POWER(CAST(2 as BIGINT), V-1))
FROM   N
WHERE  V <= LEN(@input)
```

Result:

```
9223372036854775807
```

Comment: Wow! Supports big values with a very nice performance! There's a bug in dec-->bin conversion however. It drops the first binary digit when converting decimal values like 0,1,2,4,8.

Comment: I think we need to change `WHERE N < @input` into `WHERE N <= case when @input=0 then 1 else @input end` to fix the bug.

Comment: @Rubiksmomo I like the improvement. I changed my answer to include it

Comment: Fantastic solution. I was actually looking for something to break up a binary sum into parts and that's exactly what your join does...I just left the FOR XML part alone :-).

Answer (score 0):

You could get integers from master.dbo.spt_values and use them as the weight for each digit.

```
use master;

declare @binary     as  varchar(max)    =   '1111110100110001100100111011010';
declare @decimal    as  int             =   2123942362;

--binary --> decimal
select  
    @binary                                                     as  binaryValue
,   sum(    substring(@binary,len(@binary)-position.number,1) 
        *   power(2,position.number) )                          as  decimalValue
FROM    dbo.spt_values  AS  position
WHERE   position."type" =   'P'     --integers
    and position.number <=  len(@binary)-1
;

--decimal --> binary
select  
    @decimal                                                    as  decimalValue
,   (
        SELECT  CAST(sign(@decimal & power(2,position.number)) as varchar(max))
        FROM    dbo.spt_values  AS  position
        WHERE   position."type" =   'P'     --integers
            and position.number <=  isnull(LOG(nullif(@decimal,0),2),0)
        order by    position.number desc
        FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE
    ).value('(./text())[1]','VARCHAR(8000)')                    as  binaryValue
```

Comment: Be aware that `spt_values` is pretty much undocumented and unsupported, so it may suddenly break or disappear in a future release (or any other time). Better to create your own numbers table that you can depend upon.

Comment: If you wanted to *parse* the string, you should have specified this in the original query. You *don't* have to use such code for parsing. For binary data, just [cast](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql) the data to the appropriate type. Implicit conversions from binary to numeric types are allowed

Comment: You can drop the floor, you are comparing with a numeric anyway. Floor makes no difference

Answer (score 0):

You can create two functions as below and then create a wrapper function that would have a bit input to say which format are you trying to convert.

**Converting binary to decimal**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[BinaryToDecimal]
(
    @Input varchar(255)
)
RETURNS bigint
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @Cnt tinyint = 1
    DECLARE @Len tinyint = LEN(@Input)
    DECLARE @Output bigint = CAST(SUBSTRING(@Input, @Len, 1) AS bigint)

    WHILE(@Cnt < @Len) BEGIN
        SET @Output = @Output + POWER(CAST(SUBSTRING(@Input, @Len - @Cnt, 1) * 2 AS bigint), @Cnt)

        SET @Cnt = @Cnt + 1
    END

    RETURN @Output  

END
```

**Converting decimal to binary**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[DecimalToBinary]
(
    @Input bigint
)
RETURNS varchar(255)
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @Output varchar(255) = ''

    WHILE @Input > 0 BEGIN

        SET @Output = @Output + CAST((@Input % 2) AS varchar)
        SET @Input = @Input / 2

    END

    RETURN REVERSE(@Output)

END
```

Hope this helps

Comment: That's the code from the link posted by Alex K. in the comments. If you use someone else's code, or code from an article, *make it explicit* and *explain* why this is a solution or why this helps. Otherwise just leave a comment

Comment: I kinda like this solution. It's simple and has a decent performance.